# Show data from firebase with angularJs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, firebase

I create a To-Do list with AngularJS and connected with firebase.

My todos have 3 priority levels (high, medium, low) and I would like to have 3 columns to show only the high todos in column 1, medium todos in column 2 and low todos in column 3.

I'm learning Angular with Firebase and I'm a little bit lost.

This is my firebase structure

`-JlEFzq8BsWnlM1SVbT7 
 -Description: "todo description"
 -Done: "true/false"
 -Expired: "true/false"
 -Priority: "High/Medium/Low"
 -state: "todo"`

This is how I call the description
`{{ todo.Description }}`

This is the kind of filter that I was thinking:

`ng-repeat="todo in todos | filter:{Priority:High}"`

So I need help to show only the ToDo's with priority High or Medium or Low.

## Please Help!!!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to do something like this.

```
ng-repeat="todo in todos | filter:Priority = 'High'"
```